# Getting related tags of buttons

Tags: iphone

I have number of buttons,and I had given tag values for all. Whenever I clicked on one button I need to get the related tags to that clicked button, related tags means up,down,right and left.

And I want to store first placed tag and do compare with the next placing tag whether it is in which place.

How to do?

Please help me in this.

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Comment: Start accepting correct answers to your question. You have very poor accept ratio..

Answer (score 2):

In your *.h file declare an action like:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Assign the "Touch Up Inside" action to this action.

In your *.m file do the following:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    switch(sender.tag) {
        case 1: // action for button 1
        case 2: // action for button 2
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that tag is an integer number, not a string.

Comment: & if you want you can store the clicked tag value in NSMutable array for keeping the sequence of clicks.

Comment: but i have 121 buttons,then how can i write these swiutch cases for that

Comment: Please give more details on your app. Why do you need 121 buttons? What they do?

Comment: its related to game,for that i need 121 buttons instead of collection view i used buttons as its easy for me,now my question continues here

Comment: What your game do? What is the purpose of all  these buttons?

Comment: sorry for delay,i have to place letters on that and form a word and next word starts from the continous of previous word by placing down tags,left,right tags of previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Just log and see the tag of button u clicked.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   int tag=sender.tag;
   NSLog(@"%d",tag);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add target of that button

```
[buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

---

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   int tag=sender.tag;

   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;  
   //Now you can access all he properties of that button as well as you can change it's property whatever you like.
   int tag = btn.tag;
}
```